# Django CMS - Template Does Not Exist Error while creating first page

Tags: django-cms

I followed the instructions for installing Django CMS on my mac. When I run "manage.py cms check", everything is fine, except it says it cannot find the template_1.html. When I go into the admin to create a page, the template is in the Template drop down. When I try to save the page it gives me "TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/cms/page/add/".

Maybe it's noteworthy, I was having issues with the url prior to this error. I was not able to open the admin or even get main page to render in the browser. After searching stack overflow I found the same issue. I changed the url patterns from the "urlpatterns = i18n_patterns" to the standard. That worked. Now I have this issue. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Link to Traceback if needed:
http://dpaste.com/hold/1430437/

Comment: Hello, I am answering my own question so it may help other newbs like myself. I placed the templates folder in the wrong place. I initially had it in the directory where the settings.py file lives. Im not sure if that is main project directory or what it is called. I moved it into the project root directory and everything worked like a charm. When I ran "python manage.py cms check", no issues popped up. I was able to make my first page.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error (on Ubuntu 12.04)

Following the django-cms 2.4.3 installation instruction,

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

creates a directory *myproject* (in which manage.py resides) and a subdirectory, also named *myproject*, which contains the setting files and the *templates* directory.

I don't know if this is the intention of the authors of the django-cms doc. But the instruction

```
os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"),
```

in the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting points to `/absolute/path/to/myproject/templates`.

This should be changed to:

```
os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "myproject/templates"),
```

to point to the correct directory `/absolute/path/to/myproject/myproject/templates`

Comment: This solved it for me while using Django 1.9. The weird part is that it was working before, but then I installed a couple of pip packages and it stopped. It resumed working only after I added what you had suggested. Truly puzzling.